# activeRecord::ConnectionNot Established No connection pool with id primary found: mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning ruby on rails by a tutorials: Lynda.com - Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training with kavin skoglund. all was going fine, until, i tried running my application first time. When visiting "http://localhost:3000" I get this error: activeRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished No connection pool with id primary found.

I am using

Rails 5.0.0

ruby 2.3.1

mysql2

Configured in Gemfile and config\database.yml.

**if I go for splite3 to solve this problem, then i can not follow this tutorial.
can anyone help me to solve this issue while i have mysql2 as my database.**
Adeel Ahmed.
http://adeelahmed.net

Comment: Show your config\database.yml

Comment: it seems like your database.yml has wrong configuration, are you sure that you database username and password are correct?

Comment: Are you getting the same error if you use sqlite3?

Answer (score 0):

when you create project, you need to tell ruby you will use mysql

```
rails new projectname -d mysql
```